# How to set a reminder of an email on Gmail

Tags: gmail

How to set a reminder of an email on Gmail. Microsoft Outlook has this function to allow users to click on an email to set a reminder and notify to deal with the email at a later time because I have too many emails to handle. I didn't see it in Gmail or Inbox.

Answer (score 1):

To use the reminder feature switch to [Inbox by Gmail](https://inbox.google.com) interface.

From [Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6062813?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

**Create reminders**

> 1. On your computer, open [Inbox](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https://inbox.google.com/&followup=https://inbox.google.com/).
> 2. In the bottom right, point to Create and then click Reminder.
> 3. Type a reminder. You can include a day and time. To get repeated reminders, click Snooze and then **Pick date & time**.
> 4. Click **Save**.
>
> You'll get a notification on your phone or tablet, just like for a regular email. Learn how to [turn notifications on or off](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067586).

**Add a reminder to an email**

> Add a note to remind yourself how to respond to an email.
>
> 1. Open the email.
> 2. In the top right of the email, click Pin.
> 3. Click **Remember** to and enter a note.
> 4. Click **Save**.

See the [Inbox's popular features](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/9117840?p=transition_to_gmail&visit_id=636802852597559665-3586542876&rd=1) which have been added to Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

**As of September 2022,** you can set a reminder about an email directly in Gmail's email view. *(Do so by adding to `Tasks`)*:

- While viewing the email, click `Add to tasks` (in the toolbar)
- A sidebar of `My Tasks` will appear, with your email as the newest entry
- Give your task a name (default will be Email Subject)
- Give it a date/time.
- Have it recur if you wish.

You will receive reminders until you mark your task as "complete."

I hope this helps!

[image: Screenshot of Gmail view, how to add a reminder]